# Display the same aspx page to the different page by changing the heading of the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

not able to navigate the same page to different screen by changing the heading

i am expecting to display Add Funds and Edit Funds with the same design(aspx) in dotnet
The design of the page is designed in .aspx page, need the same design but with different heading

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Such issues can be solved in various ways.

Either, you could define condition on code behind or in JS.

In aspx page

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFunds" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

For code behind method:

```
if (AddFunds)
   lblFunds.Text = "Add Funds";
else
   lblFunds.Text = "Edit Funds";
```

For JS method:

```
if (AddFunds)
   $('#<%=lblFunds.ClientID%>').text("Add Funds");
else
   $('#<%=lblFunds.ClientID%>').text("Edit Funds");
```

> Note: I am using jQuery to replace the text. You could use other
> method also.